# I have a rigidbody which shouldn't rotate, however, it is. Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have this piece of code -

```
void FixedUpdate () {


    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.forward * Speed);

    }
    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)){

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(-Vector3.forward * Speed);
    }

    else if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)){

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector3.right * Speed);
    }

    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(-Vector3.right * Speed);
    }


}
}
```

This is a cube with rigidbody component. 
When I am at Scene mode, I can see that in Transform, the rotation is 0 for all axises. How ever, when I switch to Play mode, I see that the cube gets a rotation suddenly and starts to rotate instead of moving in the same position.
How can I fix this problem, that it won't rotate ?
Thank you

Comment: Is it a kinematic rigid body?  Do you have gravity disabled?  Is it resting on the floor?  You could have part of it slightly touching an object so that the collision system gives it a slight torque on starting play.

Comment: The cube is on the floor, it doesn't touch any other object at the beggining, it has a gravity and the Is Kinematic function is not checked..

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to do.  I was kind of confused by what you were saying.  It's probably rotating due to the friction simulation in the physics engine.  If you apply a force to the center of gravity of an object and it's sitting on the ground, there's an opposite force from the friction which will create a torque.

Comment: So how can I solve this?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do exactly with your cube.  You can increase the angular drag a great deal which will make it nearly impossible for it to rotate.  You can use the "freeze rotation" on the constraints of the rigid body.  You can also apply a "physics material" to it with zero static and kinetic friction, but then it will never slow down.

Comment: Well what you said does work, how ever, suddenly I can't move 2 cubes at the same time(1 with the arrows and one with WASD keys).. And the soundtrack music stopped as welll

Comment: That's certainly not related to what I mentioned.  You must have done something weird to one of your scripts.

Comment: Nope.. The scripts are exactly the same as written above..

Comment: Firstly, you didn't tell me specifically what you did.  I gave you three options, of which you should have picked one.  Secondly, there's absolutely no reason doing any of those three things should change your soundtrack or your keyboard inputs so I have no idea what you did.

Comment: I chose to freeze the rotation. I have no clue what caused that now it won't work, how ever It happened after I changed it...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the inspector. There is 'Constraints' at Rigidbody component. Check "freze rotation" for x,y and z.